# Вывести пользователя из БД

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Пару-тройку дней как начал изучать `RubyOnRails`. Столкнулся с проблемой, которую, к сожалению, сам решить не смог (гугление не помогло).
В общем в контроллере есть экшн, внутри которого

```
@users=User.all //гипотетический пользователь
```

Насколько я понял в `@users` помещаются все записи из таблицы `users`.
Теперь во вьюхе я хочу вывести одну запись по `id`, например логин этого гипотетического пользователя (соответствующее поле в модели `Users` описано)
Нахожу её через

```
@users.find_by_id(сюда_передаю_нужный_id)
```

В браузере это выводит запись вида `#<User:0x00000002d34350>`
Как мне вывести значения из этой записи, например значение одного из столбцов?
В терминологии рельсов я пока что полный нуб, так что остаётся надеяться, что Вы меня поймёте.
Спасибо.

Comment: Прочитайте книгу по Rails, а ещё и Well Grounded Rubyist. Определитесь, что именно вы хотите сделать, вывести одного пользователя или вывести их всех.
Пока для вывода, если не можете дотерпеть и нормально изучить предметную область, можете воспользоваться `Users.find_by_id(сюда_передаю_нужный_id).inspect`.

Comment: Спасибо. Книга уже есть. Вывести хочу одного пользователя. Действительно, не могу дотерпеть. Привык при изучении сначала собирать некую примитивную болванку, а затем на ней оттачивать то что почерпну из книги, постепенно наращивая функционал. Вот и собираю сейчас примитив пользователь, статья, комментарий

Answer (score 3):

Ну, для начала `User.all` вроде как получает массив всех пользователей, а `find_by_id` не является методом класса Array а является методом ActiveRecord, наследником которого является класс User. То есть, Вам не нужно писать `.all`.

А вообще, зачем вам забирать всех пользователей, это же доп. нагрузка на БД, сразу в контроллере берите одного пользователя: `@user = User.find_by_id`…

Дальше в представлении (view) просто `@user.name`.

Comment: Я не разобрался как это сделать, у меня в цикле выводятся записи из таблицы (назовём это статьями) у каждой из которых есть поле user_id, вот при выводе статьи или списка хочу вывести юзера, который её "написал" (естественно это всё гипотетически, потому что ни регистрации ни авторизации нет).
Поэтому я и пытаюсь сделать так, то есть при выводе статьи, передаю в find_by_id значение user_id из текущей записи. А вот вывести полученный результат (одно из полей User) не получается.

Comment: Тогда просто `article.user`. Если Вы установили связь между записью и пользователем, ActiveRecord сама получит пользователя по ID.

Comment: Да, сам объект получил, через debug (или inspect) могу его просмотреть, пытаюсь получить доступ к атрибуту login через точку, ничего не выходит, пишет что метод login не найден(

Comment: А как Вы логин выводите, киньте прямо кусок erb

Comment: Странно, сейчас вообще достучатся не получается ни до чего, походу появились ошибки которые к этой теме не относятся, буду пока разбираться с ними.
Спасибо за помощь, думаю после того как разберусь с ошибками Ваши рекомендации дадут положительный результат.

Comment: @Deadik, ну если будут вопросы – пишите ВК, у меня в профиле ссылка указана…